# Complete word filtering

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a DataTable version 1.10.19.

There is a list in the table, quite large. Trying to filter by file extensions (e.g. .zip or .rar).
Everything finds good, but there is a problem. For instance. Files found:

- Name: ---------------------------- Path:
- WinRAR.exe ----- C: \ Program Files \ WinRAR \ WinRAR.exe
- SteamLibrary.lnk ------ E: \ SteamLibrary
- gamemode.rar.lnk ----- C: \ Users \ HelloWorld \ Desktop \
  gamemode.rar
- build.rar.lnk ----- C: \ Users \ HelloWorld \ Desktop \ build.rar

When trying to make a filter, all 4 lines remain, because there is a `rar` in the line `SteamLibrary.lnk` and a dot, the same in the first line. Why is he looking for matches in individual letters, and not the whole word `.rar`?

```
<div class="checkbox dis-inline noselect">
    <label style="font-size: .8em">
        <input class="filter-last-act" type="checkbox" name="filter" value=".rar">
        <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>
        .rar
    </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox dis-inline noselect">
    <label style="font-size: .8em">
        <input class="filter-last-act" type="checkbox" name="filter" value=".zip">
        <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>
        .zip
    </label>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    otable = $('#table').dataTable();
});

function filter_last() {
    var types = $('input:checkbox[name="filter"]:checked').map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get().join('|');
    otable.fnFilter(types, 0, true);
}

$(".filter-last-act").click(function () {
    filter_last();
});
```

Comment: Well if I remember right the true in `fnFilter(types, 0, true);` in that says it is a reg exp and `.` in reg exp is any character.

Comment: And how to do `.` not by any symbol, but by a specific symbol?)

Comment: In a reg exp it would be `/\.exe/`, I am not sure how datatables handles escapes. It might have to be `value="\\.rar"`

Comment: `value="\.rar"` - That's how mine works, let's see how it will work in the future. Thanks for the tip.